# Discord bot - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pycord

I'm making a discord bot with database and I ran into this problem 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.client.user:
            return
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {}".format(message.guild.id))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        channel =self.client.get_channel(int(result[0]))
        await channel.send(message.content)
```

The Error :

```
  File "c:\Users\User-KMC\Discord bot\cogs\test.py", line 27, in on_message
    channel =self.client.get_channel(int(result[0]))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: From the [documentation for `fetchone()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html): "This method retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a single sequence, *or `None` if no more rows are available* [emphasis mine]." That means that `result` could be either a row or `None`.